# PHP not receiving JSON send by Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to send some JSON data to a PHP file using Ajax. Here is my **JavaScript code**:

```
function updateJSON(){
    var xmlhttpa;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttpa = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttpa = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    };
    xmlhttpa.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttpa.readyState==4 && xmlhttpa.status==200){
            console.log("Sent")
        }
    };
    xmlhttpa.open("POST", "update.php", true);
    xmlhttpa.send("json=" + JSON.stringify(json));
};
```

And here is the **PHP file** that processes the request:

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST["json"];
    file_put_contents('data.json', $json);
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. **How can I repair my code?**

Please, no jQuery.

*Thanks!*

Also, if you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve this question.

Comment: In my JavaScript, that is the data I am trying to send.

Comment: what's not working? what error do you get?

Comment: @Touchpad Surprisingly, I get no errors exempt for the fact that the JSON file is wiped clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add line with setting `Content-type` when you `POST` your data.Try this:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Also :

```
xmlhttp.send("json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json)));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not very familiar with Ajax.